# Value not getting assigned in Android Java

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to assign a value of count of documents under a `firebase firestore`. i'm assigning to variable i. But in `logcat`, it gives me correct value, but when i assign to variable i and use it below, it still gives `value 0`.

below is the code

```
public class FirestoreNew extends AppCompatActivity {

    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    FirebaseFirestore mfirebasefs = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    DocumentReference AllUserInfo_doc, AllTicketData_doc, AllPassesData_doc;
    CollectionReference UserData, TicketData, PassData;
    int i = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_firestore_new);

        //Auth Purpose
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        //Document Reference
        AllUserInfo_doc = mfirebasefs.collection(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail())
                .document("AllUserData");
        AllTicketData_doc = mfirebasefs.collection(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail())
                .document("AllTicketsData");
        AllPassesData_doc = mfirebasefs.collection(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail())
                .document("AllPassesData");

        //Collection Reference
        UserData = AllUserInfo_doc.collection("UserDataCollection");
        TicketData = AllTicketData_doc.collection("TicketsList");
        PassData = AllPassesData_doc.collection("PassesList");



       TicketData.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.d("TAG", task.getResult().size() + "");
                    i = task.getResult().size();
                } else {
                    Log.d("TAG", "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                }
            }
       });


       i = i + 1;
       String s = "Ticket" + i;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //Documents
        DocumentReference myTicket = TicketData.document(s);
        Map<String, Object> map1 = new HashMap<>();
        map1.put("Ticket Number", "TEST123");
        map1.put("FROM","FROM PLACE");

        myTicket.set(map1);



    }
}
```

Need help in getting the correct value of i.

My current alternative workound code, im performing operations inside onCompleteListener. However i feel its not the best solution

```
 TicketData.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.d("TAG", task.getResult().size() + "");
                    i = task.getResult().size();

                    ///////////////
                    i = i + 1;
                    String s = "Ticket" + i;
                   // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //Documents
                    DocumentReference myTicket = TicketData.document("Ticket" + i);
                    Map<String, Object> map1 = new HashMap<>();
                    map1.put("Ticket Number", "TEST123");
                    map1.put("FROM","FROM PLACE");

                    myTicket.set(map1);
                    //////////////
                } else {
                    Log.d("TAG", "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                }
            }
       });
```

Comment: Yes it's the best solution. In the first case, you're not waiting for the response properly, it's an async call, so you're doing i = i + 1 just after calling get(), you're not waiting for the response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your onCompleteListener is working asynchronously, which means that(usually) before `i` gets it's value assigned, the `i = i+1` part of code is already over. You should stick to your workaround, which is actually a valid solution. Cheers!